# Use wp website icon in code

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use the wp website icon one would upload in wp-admin inside the custom theme `header.php` without having to precise the location of the image.

This basically explained:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't seem to find an equivalent to `<?php the_title(); ?>`
Is there any other way I could achieve this effect?

Comment: any thing you had trying?

Comment: The only code I have found included specifying the src="" of the image staticly, which is something I'd like to ommit. Might be bad google skills

Comment: PRetty sure that's just a reference to a logo or something. Look at the code that's out putting that image